# Is there a shortcut for 'SELECT * FROM table' in relational algebra?

Tags: database-design, relational-algebra

## Problem

A question I once found on a test was worded as such:

> *Report the book information for the book with ISBN=43221*

The relational schema for a book is depicted below:

*π<sub>ISBN, title, type, NumPages, edition, sequel, name</sub>(σ<sub>ISBN=43221</sub>(Book))*

This is essentially the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM Book WHERE ISBN=43221.
```

I wrote out all the attributes in the Projection statement on the test, but I had the feeling there was a quicker way to do it.

## Question

Is there a shortcut way of displaying all the information of one tuple in Relational Algebra, or must all attributes be written out in the Project statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

In [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) the relation

*Book*

corresponds to

```
select * from Book
```

If you want to restrict to some rows you apply a *selection σ*:

*σ<sub>ISBN=43221</sub>(Book)*

In SQL this is a *where-clause* like

```
select * from Book where ISBN=43221
```

If you want to reduce the columns you need a *projection π*:

*π<sub>ISBN, title, type</sub>(σ<sub>ISBN=43221</sub>(Book))*

In SQL this is a *select-list* different from `*`:

```
select ISBN, title from Book where ISBN=43221
```

Comment: In order to get a projection, you may need to use SELECT DISTINCT in some cases.  In this case the results are already distinct, because ISBN is distinct.  But, in other cases, you might get multiple rows with the same value

Answer (score 0):

In relational algebra you can write query in this way:

**Select**   ISBN = 43221   (**Book**)